# array to public variable in php

Tags: php

I have a array i want its value to be "public $somevariable". Here is my function how it looks like.

```
public function __construct(){
        global $database;
        $result = $database->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".self::$tabel_name."");
        if (!$result) {
            echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
            exit;
        }
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $attributes_var = array();
            while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result)) {
                $attributes_var[] = $row[0];
            }
        }
        foreach($attributes_var as $key)
        {
            public $$key;
        }
    }
```

But its showing syntax error on "public $$key". I want to use the dynamic generated variable as public variable and want to use them outside the class.

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do like below, the default value is `null`.

```
foreach($attributes_var as $key)
{
    $this->{$key} = null;
}
```